# Use git lfs migrate only on master branch

Tags: git

I want to migrate files with ".pt" and ".params" extension and rewrite history for those files, only in my master branch.

So, I tried using:

```
git lfs migrate import --include="*.pt, *.params" --include-ref=refs/heads/master
```

but it seems other branches are being affected as well:

```
migrate: Sorting commits: ..., done.                                                                                                                                                         
migrate: Rewriting commits: 100% (411/411), done.                                                                                                                                            
  fix_bug                   xxxxx -> yyyyy
  master                    xxxxx -> yyyyy
  master_backup             xxxxx -> yyyyy
  pytorch                   xxxxx -> yyyyy
```

How can I prevent this?

EDIT: based on the comment and the answer provided until now, I seem to understand my idea of just doing this for the master branch was wrong.

So, if I rewrite the history by moving the ".pt" and ".params" files to LFS for all branches, will I have to force push everything to remote at the end?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by rewriting only the master branch, and what your goal in doing so is? How should the other branches be related to the new master branch?

Comment: I just thought it would be possible to transfer the files only on master, and leave the other branches unchanged. But from your comment and the answer provided so far, I seem to understand this is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also rewrite the branches that branch off of `master` if you change `master`, or the deltas won't match anymore and you can't rebuild them when needed.

Remember, LFS changes the contents of the files themselves.